# create site with Codeigniter without database support

Tags: websites, codeigniter

What approach could You suggest, If I don't have mysql or other database support on webhost, but I need to store data ( textual information ) for website somewhere. It's informative site for school - approx 20  to 50 visitors per day, 6 to 7 categories with 3 to 5 subcategories.
Would xml files be normal ?

Comment: A database would be normal, xml files would be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML would be perfectly fine, especially with the amount of data I'm supposing you are going to be getting/generating, a csv type list with a parser of some sort (jscript, ajax, php) that could handle it would also be acceptable.

I would also contact your webhost to find out what they have for PHP support, because if they do it should have SQLite built in if nothing else.  If your webhost has no dynamic languages allowed (PHP etc) I would just suggest scrapping them and finding another that supports what you need in the first place.

Comment: I cant move to other webhost!

Comment: Since you're using codeigniter, we'll assume that you have PHP then, so you should be fine with SQLite unless your host sucks more than a "lady of the evening" on a busy night.

Comment: @wolf3d, in case you haven't looked into SQLite because it sounds too much like a database with a server component, it's not. It stores data in files, but lets you access it in nice SQLy ways, instead of having to parse XML or CSV or whatever...

Comment: already sent msg to server admin for this information about SQLite

Comment: i checked phpinfo page myself, looks that there is no SQLite support at all...

Comment: The website is located on free host that comes free to all customers, that use internet from that company. Limited space + php5 and no mysql database. But I contacted admin, he says it's ok to give one database for free host to so the problem's gone. After all thanks for Your answers (!)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your webhost did something to cripple PHP, you *do* have SQLite support.  Thats built into PHP5.  That only requires the ability to read/write to local files.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the data to flat files as a JSON string. PHP has very good support for encoding and decoding arrays or objects as JSON.

XML is bloated and often difficult to work with in PHP. Save yourself a lot of time with JSON.

You could even have multiple flat files each to represent what would typically be a table in a database...

- categories.txt
- products.txt

Comment: Upvoted as the simplest solution. I added an answer with code samples

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Jekyll Static Site Generator](http://jekyllrb.com/). It requires Ruby to be installed on your local development machine. It uses a simple template language that gets compiled down to static HTML files you can FTP to a web server. It's what [GitHub](https://pages.github.com/) uses when you host your own documentation sites for a Git repository.

Using something like CodeIgniter without a database feels like you are hitting a thumbtack with a sledge hammer, especially if you are the one doing all the updates.